# Urls.py not updating on Django production server , which uses nginx and gunicorn

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, django, gunicorn

I am currently hosting a Django Webapp on an AWS EC2 instance, To run it in production mode I use NGINX and gunicorn.

The **Error** that I am facing is:

**The production server doesnt seem to update urls.py, no matter what I do**

*App used to transfer files from local file to instance* : **FileZilla**

*Steps that I have taken trying to solve the issue:*

1. Deleting the urls.py and rewriting it
2. Checking if other files also refuse to get updated

   RESULT of 2nd step: Other files are successfully getting updated, I tested with static files
   and with index.html
3. Checking if the file is updated in the instance using **The **nano** editor**

   RESULT of 3rd step: The file is properly updated in the instance, with all changes being
   reflected
4. Running it on the instance using `python manage.py runserver` (for development purposes), and
   found out that the urls.py is getting updated properly when using runserver

Other Information:

1.Everything was getting updated properly just yesterday, but suddenly it decides to act rebellious

2. I have updated all packages using `sudo yum install`
3. I have restarted nginx and gunicorn: using commands such as :

   `sudo systemctl start gunicorn`

   `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn`

   `sudo systemctl restart nginx`
4. I have tried checking for errors using `sudo nginx -t`, but no errors show up
5. I've checked the error logs, using `sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` , but no errors show
   up here either

How do I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Your application is dynamically rewriting urls.py? Check wherever it is [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/) for any relevant messages.

Comment: Im sorry, but this is the first time im hearing about logging , so it might take me sometime to figure out how to 'log' , so my next response might take some time and thank you for helping me anyways

Comment: And regarding the dynamically rewriting urls.py.. in the production server yes, it isnt getting updated, rather than rewriting .... but when I host it using manage.py runserver , it seems to work just fine, and the same files are used in both production and development

Comment: You can click the link to find out about logging. The defaults are shown at the end of the page. If you didn't configure logging then they'll be sent to stdout or stderr and end up in the systemd journal (unless you configured the systemd service unit to redirect those).

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ive also noticed that view.py didnt update, and that the only thing that updates properly is html files and static files, Im working on the logs right now. but thought, I should let you know this observation, incase this cld tell you more abt my issue

Comment: MIchealllll I solved it ...... it turns out that I needed to restart my gunicorn using `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`, thank you so much for trying to help me , especially introducing me to logs, ill look into those

Comment: Bonus points for writing a question actually quoting the key problem.. ***restarting** [..] gunicorn using [..] **start** [instead of restart]* ;)

Comment: appreciate the upvote!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution.

Steps taken to solve it:

1. I tried to use `python3 manage.py runserver` on my instance, and found out that the files were updated fine , therefore the issue was with the production side
2. I figured out that only static and html files were being updated (nginx serves those) , so the problem was not with that
3. I was using gunicorn to help with the views.py and urls.py and other such files, so the problem could be with gunicorn

FINAL SOLUTION:

So I ran the command `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`, and the code worked perfectly